# Using std::unique_ptr.reset() to change the object under pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I wanted to use the Proxy design pattern in order to be able to "invalidate" the functionality of my object. In my design the NullObject used as the invalidated object is a static variable.

Is using the std::unique_ptr.reset with the pointer to the static variable a legal solution to this problem ?

I have tried to do it in visual studio and everything worked correctly, however I am worried about the unique_ptr destructor and what it might wanna try to do with the static variable.

```
class Proxy : public IExtendedInterface
{
public:
    Proxy(std::unique_ptr<IInterface> object)
       : heldObject(std::move(object))
    {}
    void invalidate() override
    {
        heldObject.reset(&nullObject);
    }
    void someMethod() override
    {
        heldObject->someMethod();
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<IInterface> heldObject;
    static NullObject nullObject;

};

class Object : public IInterface
{
public:
    void someMethod() override
    {
        std::cout << "Called from object";
    };

class NullObject : public IInterface
{
public:
    void someMethod() override
    {
        std::cout << "Called from NullObject";
    };
};
```

Comment: Making  a unique_ptr point at a statically allocated  object is not a good idea (in fact, you will be off into UB land). You use smart pointers when you want to deal with things that have been dynamically allocated.

Comment: I know, but I need the unique_ptr for the dynamically allocated object which is moved via the constructor.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with unique_ptr, the problem is your use of that statically allocated object to indicate the pointer is no longer in use.

Comment: So should i rather make the heldObject and the static nullObject both a shared_ptr ?

Comment: I'm far from convinced that  you need a nullObject at all.

Comment: You could create a current pointer, that holds the value of the unique_ptr or the address of the nullObject.

Comment: Using a static object introduces potential static initialization and deinitialization problems if care is not taken while the program is starting or ending.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special nullObject, you can just call `std::unique_ptr.reset()` and `std::unique_ptr::operator bool` will return false indicating that pointer holds null pointer and should not be dereferenced.

Also notice that making `unique_ptr` point to statically allocated object may cause double free issues if it ever gets out of scope at this state.

Comment: Even a single free is wrong for a statically allocated object referenced via a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. Firstly I would question the need for a "null" object. They do have their uses but there are also other ways to go.

One solution is to simple create a new "unique" `NullObject` for each pointer but if your determined to have only **one** `NullObject` then maybe consider a *singleton* pattern.

One problem with *static* objects is you can't always control when they are created and when they are destroyed. The singleton pattern solves the creation problem but the destruction problem depends on your situation.

If the destructor of the `NullObject` never needs to be called you can simply use the *pointer* based singleton which never gets destroyed.

Then you can create a custom *deleter* for your `unique_ptr` to avoid deleting the *singleton*.

Something like this:

```
class Object
{
public:
    virtual ~Object() = default;
};

// make this inline or extern (and define it elsewhere)
// to ensure only one instance
inline Object* null_object()
{
    // create the null version here
    class NullObject: public Object{};

    // Never gets deleted so it is SAFE during program close-down
    // ASSUMING calling its destructor is not required!
    static NullObject* null_object = new NullObject;

    return null_object;
}

// special deleter avoids deleting the null object
struct ObjectDeleter
{
    void operator()(Object* o) const
    {
        if(o != null_object())
            delete o;
    }
};

// special version of a unique_ptr that uses the deleter
using ObjectUniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<Object, ObjectDeleter>;
```

Now use `ObjectUniquePtr` in your application code.

```
auto op = ObjectUniquePtr(null_object());
```